# Check query string (PHP)

Tags: php, query-string

I use a query string, for example `test.php?var=1`.

How can I check if a user types anything after that, like another string...

I try to redirect to index.php if any other string (query string) follows my `var` query string.

Is it possible to check this?

For example:

```
test.php?var=12134  (This is a good link..)
test.php?a=23&var=123 (this is a bad link, redirect to index..)
test.php?var=123132&a=23 (this is a bad link, redirect to index..)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but if you're not interested in the positioning of the parameters this should work:

```
if ( isset($_GET['var']) && count($_GET) > 1 ) {
    //do something if var and another parameter is given
}
```

Comment: I have only one query parameter, so this solution is good for me..Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Look in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Tom Haigh’s answer, you could also get the difference of the arguments you expect and those you actually get:

```
$argKeys = array_keys($_GET);
$additionalArgKeys = array_diff($argKeys, array('var'));
var_dump($additionalArgKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

> test.php?a=23?var=123 (this is a bad link, redirect to index..)

In this case, you only have one variable sent, named "`a`" containing the value "`a?var=123`", therefore it shouldn't be a problem for you.

> test.php?var=123132&a=23 (this is a bad link, redirect to index..)

In this case you have two variables sent, ("`a`" and "`var`").

In general you can check the `$_GET` array to see how many variables have been sent and act accordingly, by using `count($_GET)`.

Comment: I edited my question, but your solution is same as Tom. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get rid of unwanted parameters. This is usually done for security reasons.

There won't be a problem, however, if you preinitalize every variable you use and only use variables with $_GET['var'], $_POST['var'] or $_REQUEST['var'].